# How to make a cloud of words in dataframe with lists?

Tags: python, pandas, list, word-cloud

In Python 3 and pandas I have this dataframe "proposicoes" with a column with a list of words. The column is named "ementa_token"

I want to make a cloud of words from the column "ementa_token". Each line has a list of words:

```
proposicoes[proposicoes['id'] == '465465']['ementa_token'].iloc[0]
['Comunica',
 'Excelentíssimo',
 'Senhor',
 'Presidente',
 'República',
 'sanção',
 'projeto',
 'lei',
 'Institui',
 'Fundo',
 'Nacional',
 'Idoso',
 'autoriza',
 'deduzir',
 'imposto',
 'renda',
 'devido',
 'pessoas',
 'físicas',
 'jurídicas',
 'doações',
 'efetuadas',
 'Fundos',
 'Municipais',
 'Estaduais',
 'Nacional',
 'Idoso',
 'altera',
 'Lei',
 'nº',
 '9250',
 '26',
 'dezembro',
 '1995',
 'restitui',
 'arquivo',
 'Congresso',
 'Nacional',
 'dois',
 'autógrafos',
 'texto',
 'ora',
 'convertido',
 'Lei',
 'nº',
 '12213',
 '20',
 'janeiro',
 '2010']
```

I tried this way:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

wordcloud = WordCloud(width=800, height=400).generate(proposicoes['ementa_token'])
plt.figure( figsize=(30,20) )
plt.imshow(wordcloud)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

I had this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-c072e91a9fe7> in <module>
----> 1 wordcloud = WordCloud(width=800, height=400).generate(proposicoes['ementa_token'])
      2 plt.figure( figsize=(30,20) )
      3 plt.imshow(wordcloud)
      4 plt.axis("off")
      5 plt.show()

c:\users\reinaldo\documents\code\palavras\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud.py in generate(self, text)
    603         self
    604         """
--> 605         return self.generate_from_text(text)
    606 
    607     def _check_generated(self):

c:\users\reinaldo\documents\code\palavras\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud.py in generate_from_text(self, text)
    584         self
    585         """
--> 586         words = self.process_text(text)
    587         self.generate_from_frequencies(words)
    588         return self

c:\users\reinaldo\documents\code\palavras\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud.py in process_text(self, text)
    551         regexp = self.regexp if self.regexp is not None else r"\w[\w']+"
    552 
--> 553         words = re.findall(regexp, text, flags)
    554         # remove stopwords
    555         words = [word for word in words if word.lower() not in stopwords]

c:\users\reinaldo\documents\code\palavras\lib\re.py in findall(pattern, string, flags)
    221 
    222     Empty matches are included in the result."""
--> 223     return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
    224 
    225 def finditer(pattern, string, flags=0):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Does this mean that the code is not reading the words in the lists of each line? Please, does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TypeError is quite clear, WordCloud expects a string not a Series. Combine the lists in the columns and then join,

```
wordcloud = WordCloud(width=800, height=400).generate(' '.join(proposicoes['ementa_token'].sum())
```

Option 2:

```
data = ' '.join(np.concatenate(df.col2))
wordcloud = WordCloud(width=800, height=400).generate(' '.join(data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I had this error with this command: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found

Comment: I did it that way. First I created values ->  values = ','.join(str(v) for v in proposicoes['ementa_token'])

Comment: So I did the generate with values: wordcloud = WordCloud(width=800, height=400).generate(values)

Comment: The way I did it now worked. Thanks again, I'll test with your suggestions now